# Magento. Save static block from custom form. Can't save stores

Tags: magento, content-management-system, magento-1.5

I have a task:

save from frontend static block.

The code which i tried was

```
public function savebannerAction(){
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
    $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    $block_id = $post['block_id'];
    $content = $post['content'];    

    $data = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->load($block_id)->getData();            
    $data['content'] = $content;
    Mage::getModel('cms/block')->load($block_id)->setData($data)->save();       
    $this->_redirectUrl($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}
```

And simply

```
public function savebannerAction(){
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
    $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    $block_id = $post['block_id'];
    $content = $post['content'];    
    Mage::getModel('cms/block')->load($block_id)->setContent($content)->save();         
    $this->_redirectUrl($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}
```

But in both ways what I get is: Content is saved, BUT stores are droped to empty. So block removed from currently selected shops. Or I should also include form_key into data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that saving function expects 'stores' key, but not 'store_id'.

```
$model->setData('stores',$model['store_id']);
```